# How to compare custom product bundles in Drupal Commerce

Tags: views, commerce

I am a Drupal Commerce newbie, and would like advice on how to accomplish a particular project requirement.

I have two kinds of products - Panel and Converter. Each project has a mix of those panels and converters. The type and amount of each panel and converter comes from a custom module. Each of these converters and panels have different prices.

I'm supposed to create a view with the top 5 combinations of converters and panels, sorted by price and allow the user to select the one they want, which then goes into the cart.

I hope that all made sense...

Does anyone know of any tools, modules, or methods that I could look into to accomplish this task? I feel like I'm looking for the ability to create dynamic product bundles, that are then able to be put into a view to compare. Is that even possible?

Thanks for the help

NOTE: I am just beginning this part of the project, so if this is easily accomplished with ubercart or some other ecommerce module, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 3):

For comparing drupal commerce products check out this module: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_comparison

There is also a module available which allows you to create product bundles using products of your choosing: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle